# autocomplete has stopped working with android sdk

Tags: android, eclipse

For some reason auto complete no longer works. for example when writing code using the android bitmap class, when i use the dot operator eclipse would suggest methods for that object instance. how do you turn this feature back on?

thanks mat.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure but choosing from menu Eclipse/Preferences.. And continuing to Java/Editor/Content Assist in opening dialog could be what you're looking for.

Comment: @harism hi everything seems ok there. auto activation triggers for java is set to the dot operator

Comment: In that case, if "Restore Defaults" doesn't fix your problem either, I'm very much clueless how to continue.

Comment: does ctrl+space bring up autocomplete?

Comment: @jkhouw1 no, that is the feature I'd like

Comment: I've had this problem too. I've noticed that if I "Close Project" and "Open Project" again, I get exactly one autocomplete which shows android.* classes. Further autocompletes omit them.

Comment: Actually updating to the latest ADK seems to have solved it for now.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

I had this same problem. Here is how I solved it.

In Eclipse go to

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced

And check the boxes labeled "Java Proposals" and hit Apply.

Comment: Works here too. I'd like to know why/how it got turned off!

Comment: I don't have Java in my preferences. This has only occurred since I did an update. Do you have any idea how to change this or whether it has moved in the update? Thanks!

Comment: It didnt work for me. The "Java proposals" is already checked. I tried unchecking, apply, then check them again, apply. Nothing. Restarted several times, nothing =(

Comment: The Android tools for Eclipse helpfully turned this option off for me. It showed me a warning, once, which I ignored, thinking it would come back later, but it didn't.

Comment: On Eclipse Luna on Mac OS X the "Preferences..." is under the "Eclipse" menu item.

Comment: Thank you indeed. But I really wonder why on earth it has been disabled in the first place. Android development on Eclipse is a pain in the neck, better switch to Android Studio right away.

Answer (score 28):

Im my case was API tools proposals the option that cause my autocomplete doesn´t work, here are the 4 default options that must be checked...

- API Tools Proposals.
- Java Proposals.
- SWT Template Proposals.
- Template Proposals.

  [image: default configuration]

the next time i must be careful when click Ctrl+Space =D

Answer (score 17):

Go to Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist and paste "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz." (note the dot after z) into the "Auto activation triggers for Java:" field. 
This worked for me ! Now as i type I get autocomplete options

Answer (score 10):

Here's another solution I dicovered:

I would check the other solutions listed here first and if all else fails shut down eclipse then delete the file 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs' found in the workspace directory (Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings).

Seems in my case the workspace became corrupted somehow and this fixed it. Haven't yet noticed any adverse effects by doing this.

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes Eclipse will simply refuse to perform auto-complete within a certain context. I assume the context resolution fails for some reason, and none of the resolutions mentioned here seem to resolve this aside from some code restructuring. You may want to check if this is happening with you as well by checking auto-complete on some other Java file in your project.

Answer (score 2):

eclipse use "ctrl+[space]" to show the "css/html/java proposal"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and none of the solutions here worked. For some reason, my Scheme had changed from "default" to "Emacs". So to fix it, I had to go:

Preferences> General> Keys and change the scheme back to default.