# Android Eclipse xml editor autocomplete on Mac OX not working

Tags: android, eclipse, autocomplete, editor, xml-layout

I am using Eclipse on Mac OX (I am new to Mac) and the autocomplete is working normally in the .java files, but it's not working in my .xml layout files.

I checked my "Advanced" Java Editor settings according to this post [autocomplete has stopped working with android sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916026/autocomplete-has-stopped-working-with-android-sdk) and all the "Java Proposals" are ticked.

I also checked this post [Android: Eclipse autocomplete does not work in xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114335/android-eclipse-autocomplete-does-not-work-in-xml-files) and I open my xml files with the "Android Common XML Editor".

Whenever I try to autocomplete, I get errors like `Element TextView is unknown`.

I am using the latest Android sdk version with Eclipse Juno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autocomplete worked perfectly after cleaning up my workspace and restarting Eclipse.