# Android new Eclipse android sdk bundle has no code suggestion

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I recently download new adt sdk eclipse bundle from android developer site,
It runs well but when i press control+space for code suggestion no codes are coming.
So i had to switch back in previous eclipse bundle,

Can any one help me out? so i can use new eclipse android sdk bundle

Comment: I thought it was Ctrl+SPACE?

Comment: Ctrl+a ?? or Ctrl+Space ??

Comment: ctrl+a is to select all isn't it?

Comment: i can build, and run, but editor has no suggesstion

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916026/autocomplete-has-stopped-working-with-android-sdk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [Rigotti's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529889/android-new-eclipse-android-sdk-bundle-has-no-code-suggestion/15532256#comment21999743_15529889), I found the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7355117

> In Eclipse go to
>
> Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced
>
> And check the boxes labeled "Java Proposals" and hit Apply.