# Eclipse content assist missing Android API tools proposals

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, code-assist

I updated my Eclipse to have the newer version with latest Android ADT. I decided to update it by doing a "simple" install of the whole package provided by google. The package version is adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219.  Now, I still have a code assist for java but not for Android API. I spent a long time searching google and Stackoverflow and none of it solved the problem. When I go to menu ADT> Preference> JAVA> Editor> Content Assist> Advanced, I see that the choice "API Tools Proposals" is missing from the choices. I believe this is why I do have code assit for regular JAVA stuff but nothing for Android API. I tried to create a new workspace and import the project in it. I made sure the Android libraries are in the compile path. The are because the compiler reports some error messages related to Android API when compiling telling me I should implement some methods when extending a "BaseAdaptor" so, the compiler knows where to find the libraries.

I tried the trick where you add the "-clean" in the "eclipse.ini" file. I don't have years of experience in Android programming so Code assist for Anbdroid API is very important for me. Any Idea how to bring it back?

Comment: Did you try the solutions mentioned in this thread ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916026/autocomplete-has-stopped-working-with-android-sdk

Comment: I don't have 'API Tools Proposals' either and mine works fine.  Is everything set up correctly in your Android SDK preferences?

Comment: @Tom. I believe so but, to make it simple, I just downloaded the ADK-Eclipse bundle from android where Google says all you have to do is "Unzip and go". I checked the code assist settings and compile library path and it looks good to me. Do you know of any other settings that could make a difference?

Comment: @mastDrinkNimbuPani. Yes, I saw that solution. That's where I found I did not have the "API tools proposals" in my list.

Comment: Verify that in the Android portion of your preferences that your SDK location is correct and also verify that you are targeting a version that you have already downloaded

Comment: @Tom. I checked and I'm using API level 10 which is loaded on my system. The SDK location is also OK. In fact, I can compile and I get error messages that make sense and prove that the compiler knows about the API. Errors like that I should implement "getView" when I extend a "BaseAdaptor". So The compiler knows about the "BaseAdaptor Class" in Android API.

Comment: In that case if I were you I would forget about the 'all-in-one' bundle and download eclipse separately and install the Android SDK 'the old fashioned way';)

Comment: @Tom. I'm going to do it right now. I don't see anything else.

Comment: @SylvainHuard. Having the same problem here.. did using Eclipse separately solve your problem?

Comment: @ chrisben. The problem is having multiple instances of Eclipse from different providers on my MAC. For some reasons, the links telling Eclipse where to find some libraries gets very messy.