# Eclipse not generating android button properties

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I created one android button.

```
 Button btnSubmit=(Button) findViewById (R.id.btnSubmit);
```

When I type, (btnSubmit.)

Ian getting as No default proposals..

I even changed settings in Windows->Pref->java->content Assist->checked all java proposals..

I even changed the work space..

But the intelliscence is not generated

Comment: which eclipse version are you using? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916026/autocomplete-has-stopped-working-with-android-sdk

Comment: restart your eclipse and clean the code , that might help

Answer (score 0):

I hope you do everything in such sequence:

1.Create layout at res/layout/your_layout.xml

2.Put button in this layout:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button text"
    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"/>
```

3.And then in your Activity (onCreate)

```
Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btnSubmit);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a mistake.

Iam trying to access the properties from the class which I should do from the function.

The issue is solved. Thanks for the help.