# Content assistant / autocomplete not available anymore in Eclipse for Android XML files

Tags: android, eclipse

Yesterday the autocomplete in Android XML layout files stopped working all of a sudden (I hadn't even updates anything). When I hit Ctrl + space, eclipse says 'content assistant not available at the current location'.

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114335/android-eclipse-autocomplete-does-not-work-in-xml-files) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916026/autocomplete-has-stopped-working-with-android-sdk) answer, but I don't even have the Api Tools Proposals option in my preferences.

I even downloaded the newest ADT bundle, it worked at first, I only imported a couple of projects, then it stopped working again!

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have your SDK location path correctly set
[image: Preferences->Android->SDK Location]

If that doesn't work, try deleting the files (back them up first) under:
 `<your_eclipse_workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings`
Some of these files that contain the preferences become corrupted for some reason, eclipse will regenerate them but you could lose some configurations (keyboard shortcuts, etc.)